# RSS to Database - How to Insert String with Any Character?

Tags: mysql, sql, rss, insert

I'm scraping a feed and adding the values to a database.

One of the values is description.  Description is freestyle so there can be any character.

How do I insert the values into the database to display it on a webpage later.
I want to keep the description and title text as is.

...

```
$title = $item['title'];
$href = $item['link'];
$desc = $item['description'];

$query = "INSERT INTO FEED_CONTENT (title, link, desc) VALUES ('".mysql_real_escape_string($title)."','".$href."',
'".mysql_real_escape_string($desc)."')";
```

...

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) with the magic quotes enabled will escape your data twice.

> Note: If magic_quotes_gpc is enabled,
>   first apply stripslashes() to the
>   data. Using this function
>   [mysql_real_escape_string] on data
>   which has already been escaped will
>   escape the data twice.

While outputting those content you can use [**stripslashes**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php) function.

```
echo stripslashes($data['description']);
```

**EDIT**

`desc` is [**mysql reserved word**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/reserved-words.html) and you must enclose `desc` in backticks ``

```
$query = "INSERT INTO FEED_CONTENT (title, link, `desc`)
          VALUES (
                  '".mysql_real_escape_string($title)."',
                  '".$href."',
                  '".mysql_real_escape_string($desc)."'
                 )";
```

Comment: I'm not able to insert the description into the database. No errors show up.  I have mysql_error(); line.   The desc field datatype is Text.

Comment: @vpets: `desc` is mysql reserved word and you have to enclose this column name in backticks see my edited answer

Comment: Normally you do not store backslashes in the database.

Comment: THANKS!  That Desc name was the problem.  I just changed it and it worked! Thanks again.

Comment: If user types `Foo's Philisophy`, I would rather store `Foo's Philisophy` in the database, not `Foo\'s Philisophy`... I've seen people ending up with strings like `Newton\\\\\\\\'s Law` in their data. I turn off magic quotes whenever possible and addslashes/escape user input wherever necessary.

Comment: @salman - How do you turn off magic quotes? What would your code look like then?  You don't use mysql_real_escape_string?  I've been told i should always use that.

Comment: @vpets: magic quotes can be turned off in php.ini file. It is deprecated as quoted in the php manual: *This deprecated feature will certainly be removed in the future.* Secondly: one must always use the appropriate escaping (mysql_real_escape_string for mysql database) when building select/insert/update queries. Never ever shy away from that. Ofcourse if your data is sent to a media other than database (email, text file) you don't need to escape the data.

Comment: @salman - I checked my php.ini and the magic quotes were already set to off.  So to confirm,  i'll use mysql_real_escape_string when adding and updating a db, and stripslashes when displaying data from the db.   My main use is to display the data back on my website.

Comment: @vpets: use mysql_real_escape_string when adding, updating, and selecting e.g. `"SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($u) . "'"`). When you use escape the insert/update/select query, the actual data is saved, not the escape sequences (e.g. `INSERT INTO content(data) VALUES('Foo\'Bar')` stores `Foo'Bar` in the DB). Therefore no need to use stripslashes.